# Flutter: Fixed focus QR scanner in flutetr

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I am creating an app which will use the QRCode / BarCode scanner, I have found many packages but is there a way by which i can fix the camera focus of scanner in my app or is there is a package available which support fixed focus functionality.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

qr_code_scanner: ^0.4.0 you can use package and you can also adjust camera screen. maybe its work for you

Comment: I tried your solution but that package doesn't have anything to control the camera focus.